# Session always returns as undefined in Expo app using Supabase auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, supabase, supabase-database

I am following this example - https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-expo

The login and account creation works as expected.

The issue is on the accounts page the Session is returning at undefined even when a user is logged in.

Here is the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { supabase } from '../lib/supabase'
import { StyleSheet, View, Alert } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Input } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Session } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

export default function Account({ session }: { session: Session }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [website, setWebsite] = useState('')
  const [avatarUrl, setAvatarUrl] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) getProfile()
  }, [session])

  async function getProfile() {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      if (!session?.user) throw new Error('No user on the session!')
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a persistSession issue. If you are having this issue and you also receive the following warning : `No storage option exists to persist the session, which may result in unexpected behavior when using auth.`

Then you could create a custom storage for your session to persist using expo's secure store library :

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';

const API_URL = 'your supabase url';
const ANON_KEY = 'your anon key';

// custom session storage adapter
const ExpoSecureStoreAdapter = {
    getItem: (key: string) => {
        return SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    },
    setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
        SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
    },
    removeItem: (key: string) => {
        SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
    },
};

export const supabase = createClient(API_URL, ANON_KEY, {
    auth: {
        storage: ExpoSecureStoreAdapter,
        detectSessionInUrl: false,
    }
});
```

This worked for me when I had the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

Fixed it.

The example is out of date, I should now use [version 2](https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-js-v2).

Specifically this piece of code to get session from asyncStorage:

```
https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-js-v2
```